# Jackrabbit Webdav :How to Rename the file or folder

Tags: android, webdav, jackrabbit

I'm using JackRabbit Cient for my Android.For Renaming the file or folder i didn't find any method.But i tried to make this by moving one folder to another and then deleting the first.But I think it's not a good idea to delete from client end.So,Please suggest any direct method to **rename** a Webdav file using JackRabbit.

Secondly,When i'm creating a subfolder I'm getting status saying **405,Method not Allowed**.I have no idea what it's exactly saying.

Thirdly,How can i get the **total space within a folder**.

Lastly,How to get the **access properties of folder** using JackRabbit Webdav Clint.

Thanks in Adavance,
Sha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Renaming is the same as moving inside the same parent folder

(2) Hard to know without seeing a trace.

(3) There is no such thing in standard WebDAV. So it's up to the client to calculate it.

(4) I don't think Jackrabbit exposes Access Control properties over WebDAV yet.

(BTW it's not really clear whether you're asking questions about the Android client, the protocol, or the server).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I'm using JackRabbit **client** for Android(Java).Could u please suggest me any other Webdav client alternatives which will meet my requirement.

Comment: I still don't understand whether you're talking about a complete client, or just the Jackrabbit WebDAV client library. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Julian,I really didn't understand what do u mean by  complete client.I am clear that i am asking about jacckrabbit client.

Comment: "complete client" as in "something you can download from the Android Market".

Comment: i'm able to move the file and doing renaming type of thing..but Move is functioning like copyMethod.The previous folder is not deleting.Is that the issue from my end?